# Como bloquear um arquivo temporariamente?

Tags: c#

Estou tentando assim:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
Process processo = Process.Start(filePath);
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
processo.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show("Wow!");
fileStream.Close();
```

Me parece que o fileStream bloqueia o arquivo antes de ele ser aberto, por isso da erro, um dos erros que dá é esse:

```
---------------------------
Desenhar matriz.exe - This application could not be started.
---------------------------
This application could not be started.

Do you want to view information about this issue?
---------------------------
Sim   Não   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Será que não tem uma thread de um processo já rodando? Eu não entendo muito de C#, mas isto `Process.Start(filePath);` não tem muito sentido. Está tentando executar o arquivo como se fosse um executavel. Deve ser por isto que a aplicação finaliza.

Comment: Ela abre normal, o problema é quando eu coloco esse comando do fileStream logo em seguida, já tentei colocar uma messagebox pra interceptar, dai funciona, o problema é que, em quantos segundos eu devo blockear? Entendeu?

Comment: Mas você entendeu o que eu disse, isso `Process.Start(filePath);` aqui não esta fazendo sentido. Qual o motivo disto, você tem pleno conhecimento do que o `Process.Start` faz e como ele funciona. Eu acredito que você esteja usando o código aleatoriamente, essa linha não tem sentido, é como se você quisesse que o arquivo virasse um executável.

Comment: Eu quero acesso exclusivo, a intenção é executar ele e bloquear de forma "gambiarra" enquanto o processo está em execução.

Comment: Icaro eu entendi a intenção e objetivo, o que não faz sentido é o seu código, a maneira que esta usando Process.Start não esta fazendo sentido, é ae que parece morar o problema todo, entende? Deve ser um problema que desencadeia outro. ;)

Comment: Mas eu quero executar, quero fazer o programa realmente abrir.

Comment: Então filePath não é um arquivo e sim outro executavel? Ou seja um executavel que chama outro?

Comment: Não, eu executo um programa x e depois eu abro ele com o stream meio que pra bloquear entendeu?

Comment: Não entendi, esta confuso, você quer que o programa matriz.exe chame ele mesmo e seja "bloqueado" usando FileStream?

Comment: Não, um programa em C# chama um programa X e deixa ele impossível de ser copiado, etc.

Comment: Ah entendi, edita a pergunta e coloca estes detalhes. Só uma dica, tente mudar a ordem para 
`FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
Process processo = Process.Start(filePath);
processo.WaitForExit();` e veja se funciona

Comment: Mesma coisa, é mais complicado do que parece.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim (acrescentei uma verificação para caso ele já estiver aberto)

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)).Count() > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("O processo já está em execução!");
        else
            Process.Start(filePath);

        using (File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wow!");
        }
```

Comment: Não não... Eu quero que ele seja executado primeiro e bloqueado depois, pra o usuário não poder nem copiar e nem deletar.

Comment: Quem vai executar? O próprio usuário? No meu código, após escolher o arquivo "filePath" ele será executado e bloqueado logo após.

Comment: Não, ele continua podendo ser copiado.

Comment: Eu segui seu próprio exemplo e enquanto a mensagem "Wow" estiver sendo exibida, ele estará bloqueado (Independentemente se estiver aberto ou não). No lugar da msg poderíamos criar um flag, e somente após "desflagar" que o arquivo seria liberado por exemplo.